# Jupyter Notebook becomes slow when scrolling

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have long Jupyter notebook.

One of the cells has more than 1000 lines.

When I was writing code, the scrolling and selecting the lines are really slow.

Is there any solution to his problem?

Comment: There's really nothing you can do except get a better computer. There might be micro-optimizations to Jupyter that you can do but I don't think it will improve anything substantially.

Comment: Jupyter notebook are design for quick implementation. You should consider divide your notebook into several smaller notebooks or migrate your code to .py file instead.

Comment: or else you can try https://colab.research.google.com/